# Starting a parser for scheme language

Tags: parsing, scheme, lisp, token, lex

I am writing a basic parser for a Scheme interpreter and here are the definitions I have set up to define the various type of tokens:

```
# 1. Parens
Type:
    PAREN
Subtype:
    LEFT_PAREN
Value:
    '('

# 2. Operators (<=, =, +, ...)
Type:
    OPERATOR
Subtype:
    EQUALS
Value:
    '='
Arity:
    2

# 3. Types (2.5, "Hello", #f, etc.)
Type:
    DATA
Subtype:
    NUMBER
Value:
    2.4

# 4. Procedures, builtins, and such
Type:
    KEYWORD
Subtype:
    BUILTIN
Value:
    "set"
Arity:
    2
PROCEDURE:
    ... // probably need a new class for this
```

Does the above seem like it's a good starting place? Are there some obvious things I'm missing here, or does this give me a "good-enough" foundation?

Comment: 1. `=` and `set` (and `set!`) are identifiers in Scheme. 2. Identifiers can be bound to different values (which may or may not be procedures) at different times during the program, so it's not possible to determine the arity of something at the lexical level - in fact it isn't possible statically at all in a dynamically typed language like Scheme. 3. The arity of `=` (meaning the procedure to which `=` refers unless bound to something else) isn't 2, it's variadic.

Comment: @sepp2k so it's possible in scheme to make the `=` character refer to, for example, a function that squares a number and accepts one argument? Or something else.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `(let ((= (lambda (x) (* x x)))) (= 2))` will give you the result `4`. And you can do the same thing with `set!`, too.

Comment: @sepp2k ah, I see. That makes it pretty tricky! I think for the time being for writing this basic interpreter/parser, I'm going to disallow re-defining builtin types, but that's a pretty interesting thing to handle once I have a first version working :)

Comment: I'm not sure what determining the arity at the token level gives you though. You still won't be able to do that with user-defined procedures. And either way, you just don't need that information at that point. Or at least I don't see what you'd need it for.

Comment: @sepp2k are there any unary tokens in scheme? If not, then it wouldn't matter anyways.

Comment: What do you mean by "unary token"? There are certainly procedures that can take a single argument, but that has nothing to with tokens.

Comment: @sepp2k like in C you can do `a++` and the `++` token is unary.

Comment: The operator is unary, the token is just a token. Anyway, scheme doesn't really have operators like that - certainly not postfix ones. As I said there's unary procedures, and you call them like `(- x)` or `(my-procedure x)` etc., but that's not any different than procedures of other arities.

Comment: But even in C, the lexer has absolutely no reason to care what the arity of an operator is (or whether the operator is postfix). `++` generates the same token in C regardless of whether it's used as a prefix or postfix operator (i.e. `++x` or `x++`) and `-` generates the same token in C regardless of whether it's used as a unary or binary operator (`-x` vs. `x-y`). So even if you were writing a C parser, you wouldn't need to care about arity until you reach the parsing stage (and you wouldn't be able to determine the arity of e.g. a minus sign until then anyway).

Comment: @sepp2k oh I see, so basically in terms of tokenizing/lexing, you don't care (or cannot determine) arity, so that is handled by the next stage, the parsing. Is that correct?

Comment: In languages where you have operators whose syntax depends on their arity, that's handled by the parser, yes. But function/procedure arity is not. That is, the C parser does not know or care how many arguments `f` is supposed to take when parsing a function call like `f(x, y)`. It just parses however many there are. Raising arity errors is the job of the semantic analysis/type checking phase in languages that are statically typed. In dynamically typed languages, arity errors are runtime errors.

Comment: Arity in Scheme can be a runtime thing. Eg. you do a stack machine with a env argument and the primitive and user defined procedures can check if the argument count is one more than the obligatory arguments. There are no reserved words so `(let ((define +)) (define 5 6)) ; ==> 11`.  Identifiers are basically variables so `(+ a b)` means evaluate `+`, `a`, then `b` then apply the assumed procedure object that evaluating `+` became with the result of the rest. Application not a procedure is a common error when apply finds out `+` evalautes to something else that is not a procedure.

Comment: You need very few token types to lex Scheme, or a lisp in general. Parentheses, quote/backquote/unquote, symbols, and whatever other atom types you plan to support: numbers, strings, and booleans would be enough for a start.

Comment: In most Lisp systems this is done differently: one has a READ procedure, which can read s-expressions (aka nested lists of symbols/numbers/strings/...). Code is also written as s-expressions, thus one can read code as lists. Once the code is internally available as lists, higher-level interpretation/compilation is then done using these list structures.

Comment: @RainerJoswig by that do you just mean that in lisp the task of tokenizing/lexing is trivial and basically things go straight to "parsing" ?

Comment: I think the most useful thing you could do would be to look at how existing Lisps solve this problem.  There is very copious prior art on this.

Comment: @tfb thanks -- could you please link one?

Comment: I think if you look at how, say `READ` works in CL or for that matter Racket, there is adequate information there.  If you're constrained to use some underlying language to implement it then you can still do that.

Comment: @tfb sure that's fine, could you just send me a link to where that code would be so I can look at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach makes distinctions which really don't exist in the syntax of the language, and also makes decisions far too early. For example consider this program:

```lisp
(let ((x 1))
  (with-assignment-notes
    (set! x 2)
    (set! x 3)
    x))
```

When I run this:

```lisp
> (let ((x 1))
    (with-assignment-notes
      (set! x 2)
      (set! x 3)
      x))
setting x to 2
setting x to 3
3
```

In order for this to work `with-assignment-notes` has to somehow redefine what `(set! ...)` means in its body.  Here's a hacky and probably incorrect (Racket) implementation of that:

```lisp
(define-syntax with-assignment-notes
  (syntax-rules (set!)
    [(_ form ...)
     (let-syntax ([rewrite/maybe
                   (syntax-rules (set!)
                     [(_ (set! var val))
                      (let ([r val])
                        (printf "setting ~A to ~A~%" 'var r)
                        (set! var r))]
                     [(_ thing)
                      thing])])
       (rewrite/maybe form) ...)]))
```

So the critical features of any parser for a Lisp-family language are:

- it should not make any decision about the semantics of the language that it can avoid making;
- the structure it constructs must be available to the language itself as first-class objects;
- (and optionally) the parser should be modifiable from the language itself.

As examples:

- it is probably inevitable that the parser needs to make decisions about what is and is not a number and what sort of number it is;
- it would be nice if it had default handling for strings, but this should ideally be controllable by the user;
- it should make no decision at all about what, say `(< x y)` means but rather should return a structure representing it for interpretation by the language.

The reason for the last, optional, requirement is that Lisp-family languages are used by people who are interested in using them for implementing languages.  Allowing the reader to be altered from within the language makes that hugely easier, since you don't have to start from scratch each time you want to make a language which is a bit like the one you started with but not completely.

### Parsing Lisp

The usual approach to parsing Lisp-family languages is to have machinery which will turn a sequence of characters into a sequence of s-expressions consisting of objects which are defined by the language itself, notably symbols and conses (but also numbers, strings &c).  Once you have this structure you then walk over it to interpret it as a program: either evaluating it on the fly or compiling it.  Critically, you can also write programs which manipulate this structure itself: macros.

In 'traditional' Lisps such as CL this process is explicit: there is a 'reader' which turns a sequence of characters into a sequence of s-expressions, and macros explicitly manipulate the list structure of these s-expressions, after which the evaluator/compiler processes them.  So in a traditional Lisp `(< x y)` would be parsed as (a cons of a symbol `<` and (a cons of a symbol `x` and (a cons of a symbol `y` and the empty list object)), or `(< . (x . (y . ())))`, and this structure gets handed to the macro expander and hence to the evaluator or compiler.

In Scheme it is a little more subtle: macros are specified (portably, anyway) in terms of rules which turn a bit of syntax into another bit of syntax, and it's not (I think) explicit whether such objects are made of conses & symbols or not.  But the structure which is available to syntax rules needs to be as rich as something made of conses and symbols, because syntax rules get to poke around inside it.  If you want to write something like the following macro:

```lisp
(define-syntax with-silly-escape
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (escape) form ...)
     (call/cc (λ (c)
                (define (escape) (c 'escaped))
                form ...))]
    [(_ (escape val ...) form ...)
     (call/cc (λ (c)
                (define (escape) (c val ...))
                form ...))]))
```

then you need to be able to look into the structure of what came from the reader, and that structure needs to be as rich as something made of lists and conses.

### A toy reader: [reeder](https://tfeb.github.io/reeder/)

Reeder is a little Lisp reader written in Common Lisp that I wrote a little while ago for reasons I forget (but perhaps to help me learn [CL-PPCRE](https://edicl.github.io/cl-ppcre/), which it uses).  It is emphatically a toy, but it is also small enough and simple enough to understand: certainly it is much smaller and simpler than the standard CL reader, and it demonstrates one approach to solving this problem.  It is driven by a table known as a reedtable which defines how parsing proceeds.

So, for instance:

```lisp
> (with-input-from-string (in "(defun foo (x) x)")
    (reed :from in))
(defun foo (x) x)
```

#### Reeding

To read (reed) something using a reedtable:

1. look for the next interesting character, which is the next character not defined as whitespace in the table (reedtables have a configurable list of whitespace characters);
2. if that character is defined as a macro character in the table, call its function to read something;
3. otherwise call the table's token reader to read and interpret a token.

#### Reeding tokens

The token reader lives in the reedtable and is responsible for accumulating and interpreting a token:

1. it accumulates a token in ways known to itself (but the default one does this by just trundling along the string handling single (`\`) and multiple (`|`) escapes defined in the reedtable until it gets to something that is whitespace in the table);
2. at this point it has a string and it asks the reedtable to turn this string into something, which it does by means of token parsers.

There is a small kludge in the second step: as the token reader accumulates a token it keeps track of whether it is 'denatured' which means that there were escaped characters in it.  It hands this information to the token parsers, which allows them, for instance, to interpret `|1|`, which is denatured, differently to `1`, which is not.

Token parsers are also defined in the reedtable: there is a `define-token-parser` form to define them.  They have priorities, so that the highest priority one gets to be tried first and they get to say whether they should be tried for denatured tokens.  Some token parser should always apply: it's an error if none do.

The default reedtable has token parsers which can parse integers and rational numbers, and a fallback one which parses a symbol.  Here is an example of how you would replace this fallback parser so that instead of returning symbols it returns objects called 'cymbals' which might be the representation of symbols in some embedded language:

Firstly we want a copy of the reedtable, and we need to remove the symbol parser from that copy (having previously checked its name using `reedtable-token-parser-names`).

```lisp
(defvar *cymbal-reedtable* (copy-reedtable nil))
(remove-token-parser 'symbol *cymbal-reedtable*)
```

Now here's an implementation of cymbals:

```lisp
(defvar *namespace* (make-hash-table :test #'equal))

(defstruct cymbal
  name)

(defgeneric ensure-cymbal (thing))

(defmethod ensure-cymbal ((thing string))
  (or (gethash thing *namespace*)
      (setf (gethash thing *namespace*)
            (make-cymbal :name thing))))

(defmethod ensure-cymbal ((thing cymbal))
  thing)
```

And finally here is the cymbal token parser:

```lisp
(define-token-parser (cymbal 0 :denatured t :reedtable *cymbal-reedtable*)
    ((:sequence
      :start-anchor
      (:register (:greedy-repetition 0 nil :everything))
      :end-anchor)
     name)
  (ensure-cymbal name))
```

An example of this.  Before modifying the reedtable:

```lisp
> (with-input-from-string (in "(x y . z)")
    (reed :from in :reedtable *cymbal-reedtable*))
(x y . z)
```

After:

```lisp
> (with-input-from-string (in "(x y . z)")
    (reed :from in :reedtable *cymbal-reedtable*))
(#S(cymbal :name "x") #S(cymbal :name "y") . #S(cymbal :name "z"))
```

#### Macro characters

If something isn't the start of a token then it's a macro character.  Macro characters have associated functions and these functions get called to read one object, however they choose to do that.  The default reedtable has two-and-a-half macro characters:

- `"` reads a string, using the reedtable's single & multiple escape characters;
- `(` reads a list or a cons.
- `)` is defined to raise an exception, as it can only occur if there are unbalanced parens.

The string reader is pretty straightforward (it has a lot in common with the token reader although it's not the same code).

The list/cons reader is mildly fiddly: most of the fiddliness is dealing with consing dots which it does by a slightly disgusting trick: it installs a secret token parser which will parse a consing dot as a special object if a dynamic variable is true, but otherwise will raise an exception.  The cons reader then binds this variable appropriately to make sure that consing dots are parsed only where they are allowed.  Obviously the list/cons reader invokes the whole reader recursively in many places.

And that's all the macro characters.  So, for instance in the default setup, `'` would read as a symbol (or a cymbal).  But you can just install a macro character:

```lisp
(defvar *qr-reedtable* (copy-reedtable nil))

(setf (reedtable-macro-character #\' *qr-reedtable*)
      (lambda (from quote table)
        (declare (ignore quote))
        (values `(quote ,(reed :from from :reedtable table))
                (inch from nil))))
```

And now `'x` will read as `(quote x)` in `*qr-reedtable*`.

Similarly you could add a more compllicated macro character on `#` to read objects depending on their next character in the way CL does.

An example of the quote reader.  Before:

```lisp
> (with-input-from-string (in "'(x y . z)")
    (reed :from in :reedtable *qr-reedtable*))
\'
```

The object it has returned is a symbol whose name is `"'"`, and it didn't read beyond that of course.  After:

```lisp
> (with-input-from-string (in "'(x y . z)")
    (reed :from in :reedtable *qr-reedtable*))
`(x y . z)
```

#### Other notes

Everything works one-character-ahead, so all of the various functions get the stream being read, the first character they should be interested in and the reedtable, and return both their value and the next character.   This avoids endlessly unreading characters (and probably tells you what grammar class it can handle natively (obviously macro character parsers can do whatever they like so long as things are sane when they return).

It probably doesn't use anything which isn't moderately implementable in non-Lisp languages.  Some

- Macros will cause pain in the usual way, but the only one is `define-token-parser`.  I think the solution to that is the usual expand-the-macro-by-hand-and-write-that-code, but you could probably help a bit by having an `install-or-replace-token-parser` function which dealt with the bookkeeping of keeping the list sorted etc.
- You'll need a language with dynamic variables to implement something like the cons reeder.
- it uses CL-PPCRE's s-expression representation of regexps.  I'm sure other languages have something like this (Perl does) because no-one wants to write stringy regexps: they must have died out decades ago.

It's a toy: it may be interesting to read but it's not suitable for any serious use.  I found at least one bug while writing this: there will be many more.